# How do I make the banner image go down in mobile site

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want my banner image to go down a bit so that the subject's full head can be seen. As you can see in the desktop version, the subject's head is fully visible but in the mobile version of the website, I can't see the full head and also not the full picture. How do I make the image go down a bit so as the full picture can be seen?

photo of the mobile version of my website
[Mobile version of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7h9T.jpg)

photo of the website [desktop version of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOgFa.jpg)

html code

```
 <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="intro-text">
                <div class="intro-lead-in"  style="font-family: 'Satisfy', cursive;">Welcome To ************</div>
                <div class="intro-heading">The path you won't turn your back on</div>
                <a href="#about" class="page-scroll btn btn-xl">About Us</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

css code

```
header{
    background-image:url(../img/bg.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:scroll;
    background-position:center center;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    text-align:right;
    color:black;
}
header .intro-text{
    padding-top:100px;
    padding-bottom:50px;

}
header .intro-text .intro-lead-in{
    font-family:"Satisfy","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
    line-height:22px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    text-align: right;
}
header .intro-text .intro-heading{
    font-family:Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight:800;
    font-size:25px;
    line-height:50px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    text-align:right;
    color: red;
}
@media (min-width:768px){
    header .intro-text{
        padding-top:350px;
        padding-bottom:200px;
    }
    header .intro-text .intro-lead-in{
        font-family:"Satisfy","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        font-size:40px;
        line-height:40px;
        margin-bottom:25px;
        text-align:right;
    }
    header .intro-text .intro-heading{
        font-family:Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        font-weight:800;
        font-size:25px;
        line-height:75px;
        margin-bottom:30px;
        text-align: right;
        color: red;

    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    header .intro-text{
    padding-top:140px;
        padding-bottom:100px;
        padding-left: 110px;
    }
    header .intro-text .intro-lead-in{
    font-family:"Droid Serif","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-style: italic;
        font-size:26px;
        line-height:22px;
        margin-bottom:20px
    }
    header .intro-text .intro-heading{
    font-family:Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;

        font-weight:400;
        font-size:17px;
        line-height:18px;
        margin-bottom:30px;
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `header{ background-position:left top; }` rule to your media query for mobile. This will make the image start at top left instead of center. See this: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/93sbrt9s/

Comment: Chances are it's just not enough padding on the container element / body. However, issues like this are difficult to diagnose without a non-working/working code demo.

Comment: it didn't work. The picture came in the center and overlapping all the text and also the picture didn't come down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
   body {
      padding-top: 50px; // or your navbar height
   }
}
```

It will move your content on mobile by 50px down.

Answer (score 2):

I think that one thing that can solve this problem, is you remove the attribute "background-position: center center;" from the main, and put it inner media query for each size of page (mobile, desktop) changing the second value of attr background-position, wil stay this way for sample:

```css
header{
    background-image:url('back.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:scroll;
    background-position:center center;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    text-align:right;
    color:black;
}

@media (min-width:768px){
    background-position:center 40px !important;
}


@media (min-width:480px){
    background-position:center 20px !important;
}
```

Sorry for my english, I hope that this can help you

Answer (score 0):

You could change the background position in mobile device.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    header {
        background-position: 0px 100px;//0px from left 100px from top
    }
}
```

EDIT: or you can use a specific image for mobile with the good dimensions